# Why do these MODIS images look so different?

Tags: raster, ndvi, modis

[image: MODIS images for years 2004, 2005 and 2006 over western Europe]

Why do these 3 MODIS NDVI images have such different shades of grey? The middle image has so many dark spots and the last one is also somehow not the same in terms of shade. All of them have been recorded on the same day of the years 2004, 2005 and 2006. There couldn't have been such huge changes in NDVI over such a huge area in such a short time (the area is a part of western Europe. Sorry for the missing scale but there are multiple countries in there). Am I missing some technical information? Is this normal? Because this is completely biasing the NDVI values when looking in small 250m buffers around homes for a local study in my home city in Germany.

Comment: Do you have any other reference data to check? Maybe Landsat. Also, are the NDVI values between (-1 to 1) or something else?

Comment: Yes the values are always between -1 and 1. Why are the shades of grey different? I see these different shades in many MODIS images also for example between two following 16 day time periods. That doesnt seem possible. I referenced with landsat and the black spots dont seem to match. It might be some error but why isnt it documented anywhere?